# Optimal technique to tear perforated paper along the perforation

Tags: forces, material-science

My daughter's coloring book has perforated pages, so you can easily rip out the pages for easier coloring action. Great.

Trouble is, the perforation isn't enough, and it's almost impossible to rip out the pages without tearing the paper. It is difficult to grab the paper near the perforation since it is so close to the binding of the book.

I remember having this problem as a child, too. Funny, you'd think after 30 years coloring book page perforation would be a "solved problem".

I have found myself sometimes the tearing the page at a shallow angle as possible helps, but other times not, and sometimes a sharp angle works, and sometimes not.

I'm wondering if there is any optimal angle or other technique to tear the paper, to maximize the stress applied to the perforation while minimizing the stress on the surrounding area, as to not rip the paper. The goal here is something that takes the minimum amount of time and effort, and maximizing chances of a successful tear.

Comment: Did you test it before buying? ;-)

Comment: @IrishChieftain LOL, how'd you guess? :P

Comment: Here's a [relevant meta question](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/628/paper-tearing-and-other-practical-questions-off-topic-or-not)

Comment: Strange! This question was about half a day "alive" but nobody adressed the most important perforated paper :=)

Answer (score 4):

I know creasing the paper along the perforation first helps.

Comment: Excellent suggestion.. it's not so easy to do since it's so close to the binding though. I just tried it, and it was still a bit difficult to avoid tearing the page, so I think the question still stands...

Answer (score 3):

The easiest fix which is also an option for a child is to take an unsharpened pencil and take the edge of the pencil and run it down the perforation.

You may have to bend the book back at the binding, opening the book beyond the 180 degree angle the book was designed for, but this will not create a usability issue with the book itself. :)

Answer (score 1):

Could you could run a toothpick or something similar down the perforated edge to enlarge the holes in the perforation?